# Jupyter-Lab doesn't show the path for the new internal HDD

Tags: spyder, jupyter-lab

I recently added an internal HDD to my PC but I cannot locate its path from Jupyter-Lab to work with. It works fine through Spyder thou.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a command line that can open Jupyter Lab or Jupyter Notebook from any drive you would like.

To open Jupyter Lab in drive E for example, you just need to write the following line in anaconda prompt:

jupyter lab --notebook-dir=E://